# why "was" is used in Perfect past tense?

Tags: tense, passive-voice, past-perfect, past-continuous

I have query that i have seen many sentences that uses Past Participle after "was". But i am little bit confused with Past continuous and Past perfect Tense.

Can anyone tell me the difference?

Comment: http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/verbtenseintro.html

Comment: The above link is useful. You need to clarify your question, since "was" is not a component of the Past Perfect. It IS a component of the Passive Voice. Read up on the differences between Passive and Active, and please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 4):

When you see a sentence that has **the auxiliary *be* + past participle**, it means that the sentence is in the "passive voice". You might know the "auxiliary be" as "verb to be", which means the verb to be in any of its form, and ***was*** is one of them. You seem to already know what **past participle** is, which refers to the verb form such as *written*, *sung* and *raised*; and because most of the part participles are regular (having the *-ed* suffix), the "past participle" is usually called the "*-ed* form", or the "verb *-ed*".

When A does something to B, you have two ways to express it: in active, or in passive voice. Consider:

> *This site **will change** your life.* (active)
>   *Your life **will be changed** by this site.* (passive)

You mentioned the confusion of mistaking the passive voice with the past continuous (***was,were* + verb *-ing***) and the past perfect (**had + past participle**). I think it's likely that you are also confused by the present perfect (***has,have* + past participle**). Here is how the confusion was discussed in *Practical English Usage*, under the entry 412.5:

> Students often confuse active and passive verb forms in English. Typical mistakes:
>       <del>*I was very interesting in the lesson.*</del>
>       <del>*We were questioning by the immigration officer.*</del>
>       <del>*She has put in prison for life.*</del>
>   Mistakes like these are not surprising, because:
>   1. Be is used to make both passive verb forms and active progressive tenses.
>   2. Past participles are used to make both passive verb forms and active perfect tenses. Compare:
>       *He **was** calling.* (active - past progressive)
>       *He **was called**.* (passive - simple past)
>       *He has **called**.* (active - present perfect)

I believe that it can address your confusion nicely.

Comment: ++ And even more confusing, past perfect continuous passive: *He had been being called*